# "Process exited with error(s)" when switching from draft- to final-mode

Tags: citing, compiling, draft

I have the following problem: when I compile my text in the draft-mode everything works fine. After switching to the final-mode the message "process exited with error(s)" apears. However, no obvious failure message occurs (well, I cannot find one). The only strange thing is, that Latex tells me **all** "Citation ... on page ... unknown", Though in draft-mode no problems are present.

Any hints for this?? Is it necessary to post parts of the log-file? If so, please be specific what exactly you want to know. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Please post a full, yet minimal, code  illustrating the problem.

Comment: 'Process exited with error(s)' is not an error message from the compilation. Probably it is from your editor. You need to look at the console output or log to read the error.

Comment: @Bernard that would be my whole thesis... Indeed, I cannot tell, where the Problem stems from.

Comment: @cfr okay, you are right, at least the Editor prints the error message. I used to figure out all Problems by the console Output, as you mentioned. However, this Problem does not apare in the console Output. The only Information I can figure out in the log file is: LaTeX Warning: Citation `...' on page 2 undefined on input line 19.


Overfull \vbox (2.62502pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []

[2
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex: fflush() failed (Invalid argument)
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced! @ the very end of the log file

Comment: Sounds as if some graphic is problematic. Move \end{document} until you can find the point where the problem is. Which tex system are you using?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer nice idea. I just came up with a nearly similar idea, including my text chapterwise. And than I figured out, that I had `\pagenumbering{arabic}` just at the beginning of chapter 1. Excluding this solved my problem, though I don't get the interference between draft and final... I'm using texmaker 4.4.1 and miktex 2.9.5700

Comment: Hm. Are you using hyperref?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer surprisingly, now it works, even with `\pagenumbering{arabic}` included. The only thing I did, was including my text chapterwise... no, no hyperref in use

Comment: I wrote all my text in draft mode, not caring about final mode. Just, when I finished my work, I switched to final-mode. So obviously, I didn't change anything in the code. Very strange and somehow elusive... Is it worth to still investigate?